# Google Maps JavaScript API works in browser but not in Cordova app on a device

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic / PhoneGap app that calculates the distance between two locations using Google maps `google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()` service.

This works fine when I `ionic serve` the application in a web browser but when I install it onto my test device (Samsung Galaxy S4 - 5.0) it doesn't work, and by doesn't I mean I get no callback whatsoever (from the defered object or the try catch statement) making it impossible to debug.

**My Code**

Factory wrapper class:

```
.factory('GmapsWrapper', function ($q) {

    function _GetLatLngObject(lat, lng) {
        console.log('Gmaps Wrapper - getting new lat lng object...');
        try {
            return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('*google.maps.LatLng()* error: ' + err.message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    function _GetJourneyDistance(startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng) {
        console.log('Gmaps Wrapper - calculating journey distance...');
        var d = $q.defer();
        try {
            var origin = _GetLatLngObject(startLat, startLng);
            var destination = _GetLatLngObject(endLat, endLng);

            console.log('origin: ' + angular.toJson(origin));
            console.log('destination: ' + angular.toJson(destination));

            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [origin],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            }, function (response, status) {
                console.log('*service.getDistanceMatrix* callback: response = ' + angular.toJson(response) + ', status = ' + status);
                d.resolve(response, status);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('*google maps service.getDistanceMatrix()* error: ' + err.message);
            d.reject(err);
        }
        return d.promise;
    }

    return {
        GetJourneyDistance: _GetJourneyDistance,
        GetLatLngObject: _GetLatLngObject
    }
});
```

Controller function calling the `GetJourneyDistance` method:

```
function Calc() {
        GmapsWrapper.GetJourneyDistance(52.8425701, -1.3493778, 52.8460761, -1.3363366).then(function (data, status) {
            PopupWrapper.ShowAlert('Calculte Distance', 'Success.');
            if (data.rows && data.rows.length > 0) {
                var distance = data.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
                PopupWrapper.ShowAlert('Distance', 'Km = ' + EbiLibrary.ConvertMetersToKm(distance.value) + '<br />Miles = '
                    + EbiLibrary.ConvertMetersToMiles(distance.value));
            }
        }, function (err) {
            PopupWrapper.ShowAlert('Calculate Distance', 'Error: ' + angular.toJson(err));
        });
    }
```

index.html script reference:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY KEY]&sensor=true"></script>
```

config.xml whitelisting:

```
<access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/*" />
```

**Additional Info**

I know the Google Maps script is added correctly in my `index.html` file because when I `console.log` the origin and destination variables it displays them as a lat lng object which is created using the `new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)` method.

Comment: Have you whitelisten the Google url?

Comment: Yes in my `config.xml` I have `<access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/*" />` and when I weinre inspect it I see the relevant scripts added to the head tag. Would these scripts appear if the whitelisting wasn't correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Joerg for pointing me in the right direction. I used the developer tools to check what requests were being made when using `ionic serve` and noticed that three requests were made:

- Two of them began with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps
- And the other one was https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3 (which didn't match my whitelisting rule)

So I have changed my whitelisting to `<access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com/*" />` which for now seems to have solved it.